# 「動詞辞書形＋な」はどういう意味ですか。

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence when reading an essay：

> 「ぢちらしろ、そう何回も声をかけられたんじゃ不快な気分に**なるな**というほうが無理ではないか。」

What is the meaning of になるな here? I understand 辞書形＋ない to either mean

(1) Don't do the action of the verb. ie するな！*Don't do that!*
(2) Nothing too specific, just softening a phrase, similarly to how 'la' 'leh' 'lor' etc are used in Singapore English.

I don't understand the rest of the sentence fully either, but I'm not sure whether in this case the なるな is either case (1), (2) or something else I may be ignorant too.

Comment: `ぢちらしろ` ← 「どちらにしろ」とかですかね・・？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's (1). The な is a negative imperative particle, since ～というほうが無理(= Quotative と + 言う方が無理) follows an imperative phrase or sentence.

「Imperative phrase/sentence + というほうが無理（だ）」 is an expression for saying "(*lit*) It's unreasonable to tell me/us/someone to do~~." i.e. "You can't expect me/us/someone to do~~!", implying "Of course I/we/someone do/can not~~."

> 不快な気分になるなというほうが無理ではないか。
>   (*lit*) It's unreasonable to tell me not to feel disturbed/uncomfortable, isn't it?
>   → You can't expect me not to feel disturbed/uncomfortable, right?
>   Implying: "(If you keep talking to me / calling me so many times, then) I will feel disturbed, of course! / it's quite natural that I should feel disturbed!" (≂ 不快な気分になるに決まってるだろう・不快な気分になって当たり前だろう）

Answer (score 1):

> 不快な気分になるな

*don't feel unpleasant*
な in the phrase means  (1) Don't do the action of the verb. ie するな！ *don't do that!*