# 言うなって beyond the meaning

Tags: grammar, て-form, anime

言うなって has more than one meaning.

The case I am interested in is: Don't say that!

I am wondering about the なって part.
It looks like the て-form of なる but then the english translation makes no sense anymore.
"Say become".

So, is this a grammatical form that you can combine with other verbs too?

For people with a LingQ account:
I am making the Attack on Titan subtitles available on the platform.
The above sentence (with context) can be found here on page 8.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/10cBh6DAcXgxOpwlmSFFb2oV06vgi4zRTIPhpYHUjsVA/edit
The link lessen is here https://www.lingq.com/en/learn/ja/web/reader/19330600

Comment: Related: [What does "なるなって" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97175/43676)

Comment: Thanks, that solves my question. Can I close it somehow with a flag for duplication?

Comment: It's `なるな + って`, not `なる + なって`. As for this って, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69376/5010